# Remove underline only below DrawableStart icon used in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image]

I had a TextInputLayout where I set `DrawableStart` attribute which shows icon above underline of `EditText` but i don't need underline only below drawable. Is there any way to do this by Customising TextInputEditText?

Comment: Hello Vikas! Welcome to SO. Add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: please have a look at above image link for reference

Answer (score 0):

Define your icon in `ImageView` and then define `EditText` to right of this icon.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_icon" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going at it the wrong way. The underline will always include all TextInputLayout since the underline is part of it and not part of the image. 
To achieve what you want to create a LinarLay like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="88dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
    android:background="@drawable/bgXMLFileName"/>

<EditText
    android:inputType="text"
    android:id="@+id/some_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now create another layout xml file "bgXMLFileName"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
    <padding android:bottom="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Should do the job

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="password" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: thanks btw i don't want to add new view, need to use only EditText maybe drawing custom EditText will work but which property to be changed will figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**if you don't need underline only below drawable. than you can use background null in both case TextInputEditText and Edit Text like this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email_img"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:background="@null"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_icon"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:background="@null"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]

I hope it helps you